# Good "freeware" mosaic creator

Tags: building, software, design, mosaic

I need to know of a decent "freeware" program that can take an image and turn it into a full color mosaic. It also needs to have a part count/listing.

Answer (score 5):

PictoBrick is a good one. It works with real LEGO colors and parts and will give you a parts-list: http://www.pictobrick.de/en/pictobrick.shtml

Answer (score 1):

**[Bricklink Studio](https://www.bricklink.com/v3/studio/download.page)** has a built-in mosaic generator with a lot of options for tweaking.

[image]

The software also has a mode to generate instructions and supports direct integration with BrickLink’s catalog, marketplace, and gallery so you can order parts easily. Parts generated can be optimised for price, there is also support for various colour pallets and brick types (plates, tiles, bricks etc.)

[image]